# Clear figure subplots matplotlib python

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I wrote a simple Python function to generate a matplotlib figure.  I call `plotData` multiple times from a separate script, but each time it generates a new plot.  What I would like is to always have just one plot with something like `subplot.clear()` to clear the subplots between data changes.

I need a way to identify the figure from outside `plotData` so that I can clear the plots for new data.  What would be the best way to accomplish this?

```
## Plot Data Function
def plotData(self):

        # Setup figure to hold subplots
        f = Figure(figsize=(10,8), dpi=100)

        # Setup subplots
        subplot1=f.add_subplot(2,1,1)
        subplot2=f.add_subplot(2,1,2)

        # Show plots
        dataPlot = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=app)
        dataPlot.show()
        dataPlot.get_tk_widget().pack(side=RIGHT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure if I fully understand where the problem lies. 
If you want to update the plot you would need a function that does this. I would call this function `plotData`. Before that you also need to set the plot up. That is what you currently have in `plotData`. So let's rename that to `generatePlot`.

```
class SomeClass():
    ...

    def generatePlot(self):
        # Setup figure to hold subplots
        f = Figure(figsize=(10,8), dpi=100)

        # Setup subplots
        self.subplot1=f.add_subplot(2,1,1)
        self.subplot2=f.add_subplot(2,1,2)

        # Show plots
        dataPlot = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=app)
        dataPlot.show()
        dataPlot.get_tk_widget().pack(side=RIGHT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    ## Plot Data Function
    def plotData(self, data, otherdata):
        #clear subplots
        self.subplot1.cla()
        self.subplot2.cla()
        #plot new data to the same axes
        self.subplot1.plot(data)
        self.subplot2.plot(otherdata)
```

Now you need to call `generatePlot` only once at the beginning. Afterwards you can update your plot with new data whenever you want.

Answer (score 6):

you can use

```
subplot.cla()  # which clears data but not axes
subplot.clf()  #  which clears data and axes
```

Comment: Also, if you define your figure and subplots as self.fig and self.subplots etc.  Then you can access them from the class instance they are part of.

Comment: How would you search for a figure if it is `self ` defined?  It has to be relocated somehow before the modifying code is applied.

Comment: Today command subplot.clf() is replaced with subplot.clear().